# Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4

Tags: python, keras

I learning data augmentation using keras. link:https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
The link uses CNN but when i try using dense layers as given below I get error. The error is at datagen.fit(). Description says input should be rank 4. 
How to resolve?

```
#import dataset
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

#change shape from image to vector
X_train = X_train.reshape(50000, 32 * 32 * 3)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 32 * 32 * 3)

#preprocess
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255.0
X_test /= 255.0

#change labels from numeric to one hot encoded
Y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 10)
Y_test =  to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(3072, )))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)


datagen.fit(X_train)

# fits the model on batches with real-time data augmentation:
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / 32, epochs=epochs,verbose=1,
                        validation_data=datagen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=32))
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                         
---> 57 datagen.fit(X_train)


ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (50000, 3072)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reshaped your array. The ImageDataGenerator requires rank 4 input matrix(Image Index, height, widht, depth). Your Reshaping gives rank 2 input matrix. Hence the error. The fix would be to remove the reshaping then Add a CNN layer above the first Dense Layer(just suggestion).

Comment: can i keep reshaping and dense layers and still use imagedatagenerator

Comment: Image data generator is used for changing orientation of the image so that your model still learns the features to identify the "targets". This is for augmenting dataset if you have less dataset or forcing your model to recognize objects with (as I said before) different orientations. I would not advise you to follow this practice. But reshaping can be done by adding `layers.Conv2D` and `layers.Flatten()` so I definitely recommend that.

Please consult this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946894/keras-dimension-mismatch-with-imagedatagenerator